# Let an editor change custom user settings in EPiServer

Tags: asp.net-membership, episerver, episerver-6-r2

I am creating an EPiServer portal that users will log on to and view information specific to their company. A company can have many users. Every user will need specific settings to present correct data to them. These settings are maintained by an editor, not the user him/herself.

I could of course do a admin page that connects to a simple database, but I would like to use EPiServers built in interface for handling users if possible.

Is it possible to extend the "Edit User" interface to allow editing of custom properties?

Maybe also use ASP.net's system for custom properties in SqlMembershipProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should use the SqlProfileProvider, take a look at this post:
http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Stefan-Forsberg/Dates/2009/5/Adding-a-connected-Company-field-to-an-EPiServer-user--A-love-story/

Comment: Wow, that was very accurately exactly what I was looking for! :-) Thanks!